# Authentication Filter not working with Authorization Filter in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-filters

I am trying to create a custom Authentication filter for ASP.NET Web API. Below is the code for my authentication filter

```
public class IDPAuthenticationFilter : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "testUser"));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "client"));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("testUser"));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("APP:USERID", "50123"));

        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, new string[] { });
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;

        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
    }
}
```

I have configured the Authentication Filter globally and confirmed using break-point that the filter is getting called.

```
config.Filters.Add(new IDPAuthenticationFilter());
```

The issue is if I add `[System.Web.Http.Authorize]` attribute to any controller then I get 401 Unauthorized error. I am able to access user name using `User.Identity.Name` in the controller action, but if I add authorize attribute I get the error. Is there any thing I am missing.

Thanks for you time. Kindly add a comment in case any other information is required.

Comment: Why are you adding the authorize attribute aswell as your one if I may ask?

Comment: IDPAuthenticationFilter is to set the Identity and Authorize attribute is make sure only authenticated users are able to access the controller.

Comment: @cl0ud In Web API, authentication filters handle authentication, but not authorization. Authorization should be done by an authorization filter or inside the controller action.

Comment: The reason why I ask is because you are creating an `IDPAuthenticationFilter` that inherits from an `AuthorizationFilterAttribute`. That fundamentally already sounds flawed to me , AuthorizationFilters are for authorization just as their name suggests.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I have made some changes and now I am implementing IAuthenticationFilter. Will update the question if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were couple of things that I was doing wrong. 
First I needed to implement `IAuthenticationFilter` instead of `AuthorizationFilterAttribute`

Second the way I was setting the identity was incorrect. Below is the code that worked for me.

```
public class IDPAuthenticationFilter : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter 
{

    public bool AllowMultiple => false;

    public async Task AuthenticateAsync (HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    {

        HttpRequestMessage request = context.Request;
        AuthenticationHeaderValue authorization = request.Headers.Authorization;

        if (authorization == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (authorization.Scheme != "Bearer") {
            return;
        }

        var claims = new List<Claim> ();
        claims.Add (new Claim (ClaimTypes.Name, "testUser"));
        claims.Add (new Claim (ClaimTypes.Role, "client"));
        claims.Add (new Claim ("sub", "testUser"));
        claims.Add (new Claim("APP:USERID", "50123"));

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity (claims, "Auth_Key");

        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal (new [] { identity });
        context.Principal = principal;
        HttpContext.Current.User = context.Principal;
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = context.Principal;

    }

}
```